# Factorybot - How to set Nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I beleive it's better to create a new question... It follows [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54627989/11025649) my model product has many sizes (nested attributes)

I want to create Factories but I can't make it work...

A product is valid if it has at least one size (`size_name`and `quantity`)

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :product do
    title { Faker::Artist.name}
    ref   { Faker::Number.number(10)}
    price { Faker::Number.number(2) }
    color { Faker::Color.color_name }
    brand { Faker::TvShows::BreakingBad }
    description { Faker::Lorem.sentence(3) }
    attachments { [
      File.open(File.join(Rails.root,"app/assets/images/seeds/image.jpg")),

    ] }
    user { User.first || association(:user, admin: true)}
    category { Category.first }


    # SOLUTION 1
    factory :size do 
       transient do 
         size_name {["S", "M", "L", "XL"].sample}
          quantity  { Faker::Number.number(2) }
        end
     end
   # SOLUTION 2 
    after(:create) do |product|
       create(:size, product: product)
     end

  # SOLUTION 3 
    initialize_with { attributes }
   # Failure/Error: @product = create(:product, category_id: category.id)
   # NoMethodError:
   # undefined method `save!' for #<Hash:0x007ff12f0d9378>
  end
end
```

In the controller spec

```
  before(:each) do 
    sign_in FactoryBot.create(:user, admin: true)
    category = create(:category)
    @product = create(:product, category_id: category.id)
  end
```

I don't know how to write the size attribute, my produt is still not valid (missing the size)

The error I get is `validation failed,Product must exist...`

Comment: `association: :size, factory: :size` not working within `:product` factory ?

Comment: i am affraid it's not

Comment: Did you try the solutions on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963298/how-to-set-up-factory-in-factorygirl-with-has-many-association ?

Comment: I tried yes but my product still fails like it can't be created (size is not well created so prodiuct is not valid)

Comment: I edited my question and added both solutions I tried

Answer (score 4):

You have to define a factory for size

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :size do 
    size_name { ["S", "M", "L", "XL"].sample }
    quantity  { Faker::Number.number(2) }
  end
end
```

and the product

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :product do
    association :size
    title { Faker::Artist.name}
    ...
  end
end
```

or add the build callback in the :product factory

```
after :build do |product|
  product.sizes << create(:size)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a factory for sizes

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :size do
    size_name {["S", "M", "L", "XL"].sample}
    quantity  { Faker::Number.number(2) }
    product
  end
end
```

and one for products

```
 FactoryBot.define do
   factory :product do
    title { Faker::Artist.name}
    ref   { Faker::Number.number(10)}
    price { Faker::Number.number(2) }
    color { Faker::Color.color_name }
    brand { Faker::TvShows::BreakingBad }
    description { Faker::Lorem.sentence(3) }
    attachments { [
      File.open(File.join(Rails.root,"app/assets/images/seeds/image.jpg")),
    ] }
    user { User.first || association(:user, admin: true)}
    category 
  end
end
```